# How can I record time for function call in clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am newbie to Clojure. I am invoking Clojure function using java and I want to record the time a particular line of clojure code execution takes:

Suppose if my clojure function is:

```
     (defn sampleFunction [sampleInput]
         (fun1 (fun2 sampleInput))
```

Above function I am invoking from java which returns some String value and I want to record the time it takes for executing fun2.

I have a another function say logTime which will write the parameter passed to it in to some database:

```
      (defn logTime [time]
            .....
      )
```

My Question is: How can I modify my sampleFunction(..) to invoke logTime for recording time it took to execute fun2.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how the different pieces of your code fit together and interoperate with Java, but here's something that could work with the way you described it.

To get the execution time of a piece of code, there's a core function called `time`. However, this function doesn't *return* the execution time, it just *prints* it... So given that you want to log that time into a database, we need to write a macro to capture both the return value of `fun2` as well the time it took to execute:

```
(defmacro time-execution
  [& body]
  `(let [s# (new java.io.StringWriter)]
     (binding [*out* s#]
       (hash-map :return (time ~@body)
                 :time   (.replaceAll (str s#) "[^0-9\\.]" "")))))
```

What this macro does is bind standard output to a Java `StringWriter`, so that we can use it to store whatever the `time` function prints. To return both the result of `fun2` and the time it took to execute, we package the two values in a hash-map (could be some other collection too - we'll end up destructuring it later). Notice that the code whose execution we're timing is wrapped in a call to `time`, so that we trigger the printing side effect and capture it in `s#`. Finally, the `.replaceAll` is just to ensure that we're only extracting the actual numeric value (in miliseconds), since `time` prints something of the form `"Elapsed time: 0.014617 msecs"`.

Incorporating this into your code, we need to rewrite `sampleFunction` like so:

```
(defn sampleFunction [sampleInput]
  (let [{:keys [return time]} (time-execution (fun2 sampleInput))]
    (logTime time)
    (fun1 return)))
```

We're simply destructuring the hash-map to access both the return value of `fun2` and the time it took to execute, then we log the execution time using `logTime`, and finally we finish by calling `fun1` on the return value of `fun2`.

Comment: Thank you. It solves the problem.

Is there a way I can do it without returning map like time-execution can log the time and should only return result?

I was trying something like below and it doesn't seem to work. Can you tell me why?

(defmacro time-execution
  [& body]
  `(let [s# (new java.io.StringWriter)]
     (binding [*out* s#]
       (let [return (time ~@body)]
             (logTime (.replaceAll (str s#) "[^0-9\\.]" ""))
             return))))

(defn sampleFunction [sampleInput]
    (fun1 (logTime time)))

Comment: With the macro as you wrote it, might you have meant for `sampleFunction` to be `(defn sampleFunction [sampleInput] (fun1 (time-execution (fun2 sampleInput))))`?

Comment: You are right. I meant the same. But it gives exception: Caused by: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Call to clojure.core/let did not conform to spec. {:clojure.spec.alpha/problems ........ Any help to fix this error would be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to achieve it by replacing let by def :)

Comment: Be careful with this function. Since it redirects the output stream, if the body of the function being tracked has logs, printlns etc,
1. the `s#` param in the macro will capture it and you wont see anything
2. the calculation will be incorrect since it will now contain multiple lines so ideally you would have to do
`(-> s# str string/split-lines last (.replace) parseDouble)`

Answer (score 1):

The library [tupelo.prof](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.214/api/tupelo.profile) gives you many options if you want to capture execution time for one or more functions and accumulate it over multiple calls. An example:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.profile :as prof]))

(defn add2 [x y] (+ x y))
(prof/defnp fast [] (reduce add2 0 (range 10000)))
(prof/defnp slow [] (reduce add2 0 (range 10000000)))

(dotest
  (prof/timer-stats-reset)
  (dotimes [i 10000] (fast))
  (dotimes [i 10] (slow))
  (prof/print-profile-stats)
  )
```

with result:

```
--------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.2-alpha1    Java 14
--------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Profile Stats:
       Samples       TOTAL        MEAN      SIGMA           ID
        10000        0.955     0.000096   0.000045   :tst.demo.core/fast                                                              
           10        0.905     0.090500   0.000965   :tst.demo.core/slow                                                              
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you want detailed timing for a single method, [the Criterium library](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) is what you need.  Start off with the `quick-bench` function.

Answer (score 1):

Since the accepted answer has some shortcomings around eating up logs etc,
A simpler solution compared to the accepted answer perhaps

```clj
(defmacro time-execution [body]
  `(let [st# (System/currentTimeMillis)
         return# ~body
         se# (System/currentTimeMillis)]
      {:return return#
       :time (double (/ (- se# st#) 1000))}))
```